# Alpine linux OS versioning

Tags: operating-system, versioning, alpine-linux

I'm working on a personal project with an Alpine OS (which run on a Raspberry Pi). As my project will evolve over the time, I want to save my OS with a versioning tool (Git).

My main idea is to put all configuration files into a Git repository with an installation script (like `install.sh`) that apply all files to the existing image. In addition to this, I need to place a "boot script" that clone my repo and run the `install.sh` script only at the first boot.

Do you have another idea(s) about this ? Any feedback about my suggestion ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Usually the thing that "applies all files" is the `Dockerfile` itself. There's no point in updating a docker image: just generate a new one with the new set of inputs. I don't understand why you'd want a `install.sh` in addition to that. And the `Dockerfile` should usually be small and simple enough that it can just life with the rest of your project.

Comment: I want to install my Alpine OS directly into my RaspberryPi. I have renamed my post to remove the "image" keyword to avoid confusion.

Comment: I see. There are also tools to automate setting up whole OSes that you could maybe investigate to automate/streamline the process. [Puppet](https://puppet.com/open-source/#osp) comes to mind, but I'm sure there are others.